# How to force a client disconnection from Aedes server?

Tags: mqtt, aedes

I'm writing an Aedes based MQTT broker tied to my application server, that has an object called `device` with its corresponding `id` and `mode`, that can be `enabled` or `disabled`.

My field device connects to my server and autheticates itself using its MAC address as the `id`. From there start sending messages to the application server.

My problem arises when the user changes the `mode` from `enabled` to `disabled`... I need to force a client disconnection at that moment to stop receiving device data.

My first tought is to send a disconnection message to the client that will disconnect itself, but looks like this can be a non optimal solution...

Is there a way to force a client disconnect from aedes server, something like:

```
aedes.forceClientDisconnect()
```

Is sending down a disconnection message and rely on the client to disconnect the only way to do it?

Comment: https://github.com/moscajs/aedes/blob/main/docs/Client.md#clientclose-callback